# what type of pointer does fread need

Tags: c, file, pointers, fread

I want to read data from a bmp file into a 2d array the array is a array of RGB Structure
but in vscode i get an error:

> argument of type "RGB" is incompatible with parameter of type "void
> *"

Here is were I get the error:

```
void read (RGB** pic,FILE* file, int hojde, int brede)
{
  for (int y=hojde-1;y>0;y--)
  {
    for(int x=0;x<brede;x++)
    {
      fread(pic[x][y],3,1,file);
    }

  }
  fseek(file,(brede*3)%4,SEEK_CUR);
  
  return;
}

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
}RGB;
```

And here is were I declare the array and call the function:

```
RGB** pic;
pic= malloc(sizeof(RGB*)*dip_header.hojde);

for (int i=0;i<dip_header.hojde;i++)
{
    pic[i]=malloc(sizeof(RGB)*dip_header.brede);
}
read(pic,file,dip_header.hojde,dip_header.brede);
```

I thought I could load a array into fread because the array is kind of a pointer(at least I thought so)

Comment: The first argument to `fread` is a `void*`. What is the definition of `RGB`. Please edit this into your question.

Comment: `fread` wants a pointer `void *`,  you can use an array as target, but you need a **real array** (with all data in contiguous areas) not a **jagged array**.

Comment: any pointer, but an RGB is not a pointer

Comment: Instead of passing `pic[x][y]` which is of type `RGB`, you can pass `&(pic[x][y])` (a pointer that can be converted to `void*` - which is what `fread` expects).